# app-router and web component callback functions

Tags: polymer, web-component, app-router

I'm trying to import the web component with id "test-comp" for the path "/path1":

```
<app-route path="/path1" import="test-component.html" template="test-comp"></app-route>
```

The code of the web component is the following:

```
<dom-module id="test-comp">
    <template>
        <div>Hello world</div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'test-comp',
            attached: function() {
               console.log("is attached");
            },
        });
</script>
```

However, it never enters the `attached` callback. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It just needed to replace the `template` attribute with the `id` one.